# Upload dataframe to clickhouse using pandahouse

Tags: python, pandas, clickhouse

I try to Upload dataframe to clickhouse using pandahouse. I connect to my database and dump data from table to dataframe. Next, I try to upload this data to table in clickhouse, but I get the error :(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tmedvedeva\PycharmProjects\upload_to_CH\connect_CH.py", line 17, in <module>
    ph.to_clickhouse(df, 'outputt', index=False, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\tmedvedeva\PycharmProjects\upload_to_CH\venv\lib\site-packages\pandahouse\core.py", line 64, in to_clickhouse
    execute(query, data=to_csv(chunk), connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\tmedvedeva\PycharmProjects\upload_to_CH\venv\lib\site-packages\pandahouse\http.py", line 48, in execute
    raise ClickhouseException(response.content)
pandahouse.http.ClickhouseException: b'Code: 27, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot parse input: expected \';\' before: \',"\xd0\xa6\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xaf\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0"\\r\\n"22","\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0 \xd0\x95\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0"\\r\\n"23","\xd0\x93\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\x95\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0"\\r\\n"24","\xd0\xa2\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0 \xd0\x95\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0"\\r\\n"2\': (at row 1)\n\nRow 1:\nColumn 0,   name: id_step2,       type: String, parsed text: "<DOUBLE QUOTE>21<DOUBLE QUOTE>"\nERROR: There is no delimiter (;). "," found instead.\n\n (version 20.4.5.36 (official build))\n'
```

Data from table:

| id | employee_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |
| 2 | Name2 |
| 3 | Name3 |

Code:

```
from clickhouse_driver.client import Client
import pandahouse as ph
import pandas as pd

connection = dict(database='db-78', host='http://localhost:7008', user='User', password='password')

df = ph.read_clickhouse("SELECT * FROM `db-78`.outputt", connection=connection)

ph.to_clickhouse(df, 'outputt', index=False, connection=connection)

df = ph.read_clickhouse("SELECT id,employee_name FROM `db-78`.outputt", connection=connection)

print(df)
```

If I get and upload only one column then it works, but if more then I get an error.
What am I doing wrong? Where is mistake?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Could you write which versions of py-packages are used and provide the schema of CH-table.